# While Connecting to Neo4j to Android I'm getting an error

Tags: java, android, neo4j, neo4j-java-api

I wanted to use neo4j DB in my Android project. I'm trying to connect with Neo4j database with Android, while connecting I'm getting an error. I have added a dependency in my Android app level gradle .

```
compile 'org.neo4j.driver:neo4j-java-driver:1.3.0'
```

MainActivity.java

```
Driver driver = GraphDatabase.driver( "bolt://localhost:7687", AuthTokens.basic("neo4j", "neo4j") );
                Session session = driver.session();
                session.run( "CREATE (a:Person {name: {name}, title: {title}})",
                        parameters( "name", "Arthur", "title", "King" ) );

                StatementResult result = session.run( "MATCH (a:Person) WHERE a.name = {name} " +
                                "RETURN a.name AS name, a.title AS title",
                        parameters( "name", "Arthur" ) );
                while ( result.hasNext() )
                {
                    Record record = result.next();
                    System.out.println( record.get( "title" ).asString() + " " + record.get( "name" ).asString() );
                }
                session.close();
                driver.close();
```

Logs

```
06-22 16:24:05.627 4990-4990/com.example.prateek.neo4jtest E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.prateek.neo4jtest, PID: 4990
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.net.StandardSocketOptions
at org.neo4j.driver.internal.net.ChannelFactory.create(ChannelFactory.java:39)
at org.neo4j.driver.internal.net.SocketClient.start(SocketClient.java:124)
at org.neo4j.driver.internal.net.SocketConnection.startSocketClient(SocketConnection.java:92)
at org.neo4j.driver.internal.net.SocketConnection.<init>(SocketConnection.java:67)
at org.neo4j.driver.internal.net.SocketConnector.createConnection(SocketConnector.java:77)
at org.neo4j.driver.internal.net.SocketConnector.connect(SocketConnector.java:50)
at org.neo4j.driver.internal.net.pooling.SocketConnectionPool$ConnectionSupplier.get(SocketConnectionPool.java:204)
at org.neo4j.driver.internal.net.pooling.SocketConnectionPool$ConnectionSupplier.get(SocketConnectionPool.java:186)
at org.neo4j.driver.internal.net.pooling.BlockingPooledConnectionQueue.acquire(BlockingPooledConnectionQueue.java:96)
at org.neo4j.driver.internal.net.pooling.SocketConnectionPool.acquireConnection(SocketConnectionPool.java:137)
at org.neo4j.driver.internal.net.pooling.SocketConnectionPool.acquire(SocketConnectionPool.java:76)
at org.neo4j.driver.internal.DirectConnectionProvider.acquireConnection(DirectConnectionProvider.java:45)
at org.neo4j.driver.internal.NetworkSession.acquireConnection(NetworkSession.java:340)
at org.neo4j.driver.internal.NetworkSession.run(NetworkSession.java:104)
at org.neo4j.driver.internal.NetworkSession.run(NetworkSession.java:94)
at com.example.prateek.neo4jtest.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:29)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18431)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5045)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:794)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:610)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just because there's a Java Driver, doesn't mean it works on Android.

(Although, it seems there's an outdated Android driver on Github)

Neo4j [exposes a REST API](https://neo4j.com/docs/rest-docs/current/) you can use given HTTP requests, which is probably the safest approach to use, although it'll require learning how that works on Android and dealing with JSON parsing.

More specifically to the error, [`StandardSocketOptions`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/StandardSocketOptions.html) is not part of Android until API 24, so you could try making your compileSdk and minimumSdk to be 24, but no guarantees it'll still work.

---

By the way, you can't connect to `localhost` from the Android device unless you are running Neo4j Server  on that Android device itself

Comment: can you please tell me where i can find that Rest API or you can show me any example that will help me. Plz

Comment: The documentation is a good place to start for any examples. https://neo4j.com/docs/rest-docs/current/

Comment: Thanks for the help

Comment: Note: you won't get Java code there. You need to learn how to create REST requests from Android

Comment: Ok Thank you for the help

Answer (score 1):

[java.net.StandardSocketOptions](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/StandardSocketOptions.html) was added to the Android platform in API level 26.

So, if it is acceptable for your app to target API level 26 or above, then you can at least get past that exception. However, you might still see similar issues with other classes needed by the driver.